# How can I call javascript function with thread or task?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have tried the following code down below

.cs

```
    string someone = "John";
    int timer = 3000;
    int check = 1;
    string script = "<script> runPromise('" + someone + "'," + timer + "," + check + ").then(someone => { console.log('" + someone + "', someone)});</script>";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(ClientScript.GetType(), "myscript", script);
```

.aspx

```
<script>
    let runPromise = (someone, timer, check, success = true) => {
        console.log(`${someone} start run`);
        console.log(check);
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (check == 1) {
          setTimeout(function () {
            resolve(`${someone} run ${timer / 1000} second`);
          }, timer);
        } else {
          reject(`${someone} fail`)
        }
      });
    }
</script>
```

this code can only work in the button.

How can I use it in the thread or task when I want to wait for like 10 seconds ?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Is it just the time interval you are missing? (so not 3 seconds but 10 seconds?)

Comment: Please clarify what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I want to use thread or task to call javascript function

Answer (score 0):

you can try call the promise with a `setTimeout`

**Edited**

```
string someone = "John";
int timer = 10000;
int check = 1;
string script = "<script> setTimeout(() => someFunction(('" + someone + "'," + timer + "," + check + ").then(value => {console.log(value);}), " + timer + ");</script>";
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(ClientScript.GetType(), "myscript", script);
```

```
var someFunction = (someone, timer, check) => {
  console.log(`${someone} start run`);
  console.log(check);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (check == 1) {
      resolve(`${someone} run ${timer / 1000} second`);
    } else {
      reject(Error("It broke"));
    }
  });
};
```

sample:

```js
var someFunction = (someone, timer, check) => {
  console.log(`${someone} start run`);
  console.log(check);
  
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (check == 1) {
      resolve(`${someone} run ${timer / 1000} second`);
    } else {
      reject(Error("It broke"));
    }
  });
};

setTimeout(() => someFunction(`someone`, 10000,1).then(value => {
console.log(value);
}), 10000);
```

Comment: I have some variable need to collect from .cs so I can't use this answer. thanks

Comment: @KevinLee of course you can use this answer you just need to pass the variables to the setTimeout function instead of the values

Comment: But I don't know how to pass the variable in thread, can you tell me ?

Comment: @KevinLee Have you tried the edited answer? I have added the script that you call on aspx

Comment: @KevinLee I bealive if you had the `script  setTimeout` to your `aspx` and `someFunction` to your js file it will work.

Comment: It can work, but I don't wanna click the button to start the function and my condition won't be 10 seconds but something I can't expected when will change

Comment: @KevinLee 1- you are not understanding.. you don't need any click to this to start! 2- this is collecting the values that you need to collect from c# to the function to start execute...
3- do you understand the code?